# Standards used for indoor telephone cabling?

Tags: cables, telephone, standard

Which standards/specifications (IEC, ANSI, etc.) are normally used for PE insulated indoor telephone cables?

I've scoured the internet looking for the right standard, but can only find ones applicable to PE OUTDOOR (IEC/BS 60708) and PVC INDOOR insulated standards. Is PE not a commonly-used insulating material for indoor telephone cables?

I've also noticed that most telephone cables use the British Telecom CW standards, but I haven't found anywhere online where the standards can be purchased. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The usual source is TIA/EIA-568, which also describes the cat5e and cat6
cables used for Ethernet.  I believe normal house wiring is cat3 under
that standard.

I'm not sure 'PE' (does that mean polyethylene?) is a specified insulator or sheathing material, though.   There are both PVC and other (plenum-rated) sheathing materials for cat5, so the standard is unlikely to be very specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, PE does stand for polyethylene. It's usually covered under the "polyolefin" category in standards. The TIA/EIA-568 does not seem to cover the physical characteristics of the cable like the insulation (material properties) though.

Answer (score 0):

PE is resistant to UV, PVC isn't (or rather PE is *more* resistant to UV than PVC). Therefore PE is used outdoors.

PE, though, is more expensive than PVC, so PVC is chosen for indoors.

Yes, you can use PE indoors, but at a cost (so why would you?). You can't, though, (or shouldn't) use PVC outdoors since it degrades over time.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would you happen to know of any standards that would cover the insulation for such a cable? The IEC 60708, BS EN 60708, and the ICEA S-85-625 all only cover outdoor PE insulated cables